# Get the ID of a function(this) td element

Tags: javascript, html, function, this

I send a TD through a function but I can't interact with the ID.

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td id="1" onclick="move(this);"></td>
    <td id="2" onclick="move(this);"></td>
    <td id="3" onclick="move(this);"></td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
function move(td) {
    //I want the ID of this td that I've captured by "this"
    var tdId = td.id; //<--- This doesn't works

    var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (var td in tds) {
            if (tds[td].innerHTML == "last") {
                tdFinal = tds[td];
            }
    }
    alert(tdFinal.id); //<---- This works fine
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/E6pbN/

Comment: you are checking `if (tds[td].innerHTML == "last") {` while the content inside td is empty so basically tds[td].innerHTML = ''

Comment: A HTML4 browser? If so, `id`s should not start with a number.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VHkqT/

Comment: No no, the bucle works well, the line that doesn't work is alert(td.id) I can't show the ID of td called in a function.

Comment: @Lloople Hmm... There's a comment beside the only alert in the code saying alert is working fine!? You need to fix your post.

Comment: What is your objective of tds[td].innerHTML == "last"?

Comment: @TomChung It was just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**strong text**For me it works just fine :)

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4P3jF/

```
var move = function(td) {
//I want the ID of this td that I've captured by "this"
var tdId = td.id; //<--- This doesn't works

alert(tdId);
```

}

Comment: "You don't have a problem" isn't an answer.

Comment: Yeah... It works...I tried Again removing all the code in the function and works. Was my problem, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

[Let's start with a jsbin.com demo. People love demos.](http://jsbin.com/EZIniJil/1/edit)

---

A couple of things that should be addressed:

**1. HTML ids should start with a letter**

This is is no longer a requirement in HTML 5, but you should still do it. [Read more about the id attribute here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#id)

If you want to attach data to an element, you should use a `data-*` attribute. [Read more about data-* attributes here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#data-%2a)

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <tr>
      <td data-id="1"></td>
      <td data-id="2"></td>
      <td data-id="3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**2. Unobtrusive JavaScript**

I removed the `onclick` attributes in favor of taking a more [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) approach. I attached a simple `id` to the `table` element to make it easy to target the specific `td` elements we care about.

```js
// our move function
function move(elem) {
  console.log(elem.getAttribute("data-id"));
}

// our click listener
function onClick(event) {
  move(this);
  event.preventDefault();
}

// get our table's td elements
var table = document.getElementById("my-table");
var tds   = table.getElementsByTagName("td");

// loop through each td and add a click listener
for (var i=0, len=tds.length; i<len; i++) {
  tds[i].addEventListener("click", onClick);
}
```

---

Add a dash of CSS to make the `td` elements appear clickable

```css
#my-table td {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your first statement works fine!

I've made a fiddle with an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8tgVq/2/

(check your console for the output!)

The HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="1" onclick="move(this);">a</td>
        <td id="2" onclick="move(this);">b</td>
        <td id="3" onclick="move(this);">c</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The JS:

```
function move(td) {
    console.log(td.id);
}
```

The output:

```
1
2
3
```